# How to smooth the navigation drawer movement?

Tags: android, navigationbar

I would like to ask you something about the navigation bar. I already successfully make it. But how I want to make it move smoothly. Which means, for example, when user click on About Us, it will go to the About Us interface without need to swipe left the navigation. As shown in the video, I slide left the navigation so that I can see the About Us interface.

```
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                            .replace(R.id.main_container,homeFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_aboutUs:
                    AboutusFragment aboutusFragment = new AboutusFragment ();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                            .replace(R.id.main_container,aboutusFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new AboutusFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("About Us Fragment");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_tuitionCentre:
                    SearchtuitioncentreFragment searchtuitioncentreFragment = new SearchtuitioncentreFragment ();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                            .replace(R.id.main_container,searchtuitioncentreFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new SearchtuitioncentreFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search Tuition Centre");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_homeTuition:
                    Seachometuitionragment seachometuitionragment = new Seachometuitionragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                            .replace(R.id.main_container,seachometuitionragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new Seachometuitionragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Search Home Tuition");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_contact:
                    ContactusFragment contactusFragment = new ContactusFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                            .replace(R.id.main_container,contactusFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ContactusFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contact Us");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_logout:
                    LogoutFragment logoutFragment = new LogoutFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit)
                            .replace(R.id.main_container,logoutFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new LogoutFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Log Out");
                    item.setCheckable(true);
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    SendUserToLoginActivity();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
}
```

[My apps which the navigation didnt move smoothly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2YBJ.png)

Comment: Is your question how to close the drawer after a menu item is clicked? If so all you need is after fragment has been loaded : navigationView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

Comment: yes, something like that. where to put the close drawer? :))

Comment: You can put it before return true; after your switch statements

Comment: omg! its work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Navigation drawers are smooth but if it is not opening smoothly then there must some large size images.

check the size of images if you are using and resize them

Or if that's not the scene create the navigation drawer with help of  [Navigation Drawer tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/).

With the help of this you will be able to create a standard navigation drawer for your apps.

Comment: what's the issue ??

Comment: I didnt put navigationView.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);